# Avoid auto resize of a View when keyboard is showed

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a Cross-Platform app.

I use percentages to keep the aspect of the app similar for every screen size.

So i put a view height to

> var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
>
> > borderRadius:10,
> > backgroundColor:'red',
> > height:"100%",
>
> });
>
> window.add(view);

The problem come when i show the keyboard.
The view is auto resized.
So i need that the keyboard goes OVER the view without resize it.

Note: If i use "dp"/"dpi" the height of the view is not the same in different screen devices.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have this problem before, but there are several options having the same effect as 100% height:

```
height: Ti.UI.FILL
height: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight
```

or you could achieve the same by setting the values for

```
left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0,
```

All of them should make a view fill the screen.

Please note that it might be necessary to handle orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to **set top** property then if it does not work then also **set height** with platformHeight.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your complete view looks like.  Your example doesn't have a text entry type control which is what would trigger the keyboard opening.

You can create a separate view that contains the textArea and set this 2nd view with fixed positions.  Then the main view should stay put.